# expected initializer before ‘&’ token

Tags: c++

I wrote a simple example which came from the book "The C++ Programming.Language.4th.Edition"

```
#include <ostream>

struct Entry{
  string name;
  int number;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Entry& e){
   return os << "{\"" << e.name << "\"," << e.number << "}";
}

int main()
{
  Entry a;
  a.name = "Alan";
  a.number = "12345";
  return 0;
}
```

The g++ returned an error message while compiling
error: expected initializer before ‘&’ token

ps: the & token mentioned above belongs to the ostream& operator

could anyone give a clue ?

Comment: Missing semicolon after `struct` declaration. And yes, use std. (delete the question while you can :-)

Comment: also `int number`, then `a.number="12345"` is what you intended to do ?

Comment: dasblinkenlight is right, missing semicolon after struct declaration is the cause. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You have four main errors:

First of all you are missing semicolon after the struct declaration. After each, `class` or `struct` declarations you need to put a `;`.

Secondly `ostream` is not an identifier, you probably meant to use `std::ostream`. `ostream`, in the `<ostream>` standard header, lives in the `std` namespace.

Thirdly you are missing the `std::string` header, and you should refer to the `string` class with the `std::` prefix.

Finally `number` is of type int, not of type `const char*` like the literal `"12345"` is. You probably meant to write: `a.number = 12345;`.

After all these fixes, your program will look like this:

```
#include <ostream>
#include <string>

struct Entry{
  std::string name;
  int number;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Entry& e){
   return os << "{\"" << e.name << "\"," << e.number << "}";
}

int main()
{
  Entry a;
  a.name = "Alan";
  a.number = 12345;
}
```

and [will compile just fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fcbcb7e81ef458e8).